# SOAP XML Requests in Java (KSOAP2)

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

We're having issues formulating our request to a remote API which makes sole use of the XML protocol. We've use the Apache CXF project to parse WSDL files into types (.java files) easily importable into our project. The default arguments of none were used on CXF.

We're unsure how to get KSOAP2 to format the XML according to the type its received. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kevin

```
public class SOAPRequestTest {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
    private static final String SERVER_HOST = "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/LoginService";
    private static final String SERVER_METHOD = "urn:LoginService";

    public void execute() {
        Logger.d("--> Hello");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SERVER_METHOD);
                GetSecurityInfo getSecurityInfo = new GetSecurityInfo();

                SecurityLogin securityLogin = new SecurityLogin();
                securityLogin.setUserId("testUser");
                securityLogin.setPassword("password");
                securityLogin.setType("consumer");
                securityLogin.setIP("128.2.20.181");
                securityLogin.setLocale("en_US");

                getSecurityInfo.setUser(securityLogin);

                request.addAttribute("user", getSecurityInfo);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(1);
                soapSerializationEnvelope.addTemplate(request);
                soapSerializationEnvelope.addMapping("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", GetSecurityInfo.class);

                HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(SERVER_HOST);

                httpTransportSE.debug = true;

                try {
                    httpTransportSE.call("getSecurityInfo", soapSerializationEnvelope);

                    Logger.d(httpTransportSE.requestDump);

                    SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpfull you can parse the xml by following

```
public ArrayList<OrderBills> getOrderBills(SoapObject result)
    {       
        ArrayList<OrderBills> list=new ArrayList<OrderBills>();

        for(int i=0;i<result.getPropertyCount();i++)
        {   
            OrderBills orderBill=new OrderBills();

            orderBill.setOrderId(Integer.parseInt(((SoapObject)result.getProperty(i)).getProperty(0).toString()));  
            orderBill.setTableNo(((SoapObject)result.getProperty(i)).getProperty(1).toString());
            orderBill.setBillStatus(((SoapObject)result.getProperty(i)).getProperty(2).toString());
            orderBill.setDate(((SoapObject)result.getProperty(i)).getProperty(3).toString());
            orderBill.setTime(((SoapObject)result.getProperty(i)).getProperty(4).toString());

            list.add(orderBill);
        }
        return list;

    }
```